# Spark Streaming Exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am writing `SparkStreaming` data to HDFS by converting it to a dataframe:

**Code**

```scala
object KafkaSparkHdfs {

  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("SparkKafka")
  sparkConf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");
  val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(20))

    val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
      "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "group.id" -> "stream3",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
      "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
    )

    val topics = Array("fridaydata")
    val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
      ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
    )

    val lines = stream.map(consumerRecord => consumerRecord.value)
    val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
    val wordMap = words.map(word => (word, 1))
    val wordCount = wordMap.reduceByKey(_ + _)

    wordCount.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      val dataframe = rdd.toDF(); 
      dataframe.write
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .save("hdfs://localhost:9000/newfile24")     
    })

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

The folder is created but the file is not written.

The program is getting terminated with the following error:

```
    18/06/22 16:14:41 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
    java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockInfoManager.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockManager.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:289)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    18/06/22 16:14:41 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockInfoManager.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockManager.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
```

In my pom I am using respective dependencies:

- spark-core_2.11
- spark-sql_2.11
- spark-streaming_2.11
- spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is due to trying to run multiple spark contexts at the same time. Setting `allowMultipleContexts` to true is mostly used for testing purposes and it's use is discouraged. The solution to your problem is therefore to make sure that the same `SparkContext` is used everywhere. From the code we can see that the `SparkContext` (`sc`) is used to create a `SQLContext` which is fine. However, when creating the `StreamingContext` it is not used, instead the `SparkConf` is used.

By looking at the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/StreamingContext.html#StreamingContext-org.apache.spark.SparkConf-org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration-) we see:

> Create a StreamingContext by providing the configuration necessary for a new SparkContext

In other words, by using `SparkConf` as parameter a new `SparkContext` will be created. Now there are two separate contexts.

The easiest solution here would be to continue using the same context as before. Change the line creating the `StreamingContext` to:

```scala
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(20))
```

---

**Note:** In newer versions of Spark (2.0+) use `SparkSession` instead. A new streaming context can then be created using `StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, ...)`. It can look as follows:

```scala
val spark = SparkSession().builder
  .setMaster("local[*]")
  .setAppName("SparkKafka")
  .getOrCreate()

import sqlContext.implicits._
val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, Seconds(20))
```

Comment: yeah it is working, but i have used append mode when ever new data comes it is not writing in same file ,it is creating new file @Shaido

Comment: is their any way we can keep writing in same file ,because it is streaming    if streaming is emitting for every one min ,it keep creating n number of files.

Comment: @andani: Checking if that can be done. Spark will save separate partitions as separate files so not sure if it can be done. However, you can read all files by doing `spark.read.parquet("path")`.

Comment: @andani: No problems, happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an obvious problem here -  `coalesce(1)`.

```
dataframe.coalesce(1)
```

While reducing number of files might be tempting in many scenarios, it should be done if and only if it amount of data is low enough for nodes to handle (clearly it isn't here).

Furthermore, let me quote [the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@coalesce(numPartitions:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]):

> However, if you're doing a drastic coalesce, e.g. to numPartitions = 1, this may result in your computation taking place on fewer nodes than you like (e.g. one node in the case of numPartitions = 1). To avoid this, you can call repartition. This will add a shuffle step, but means the current upstream partitions will be executed in parallel (per whatever the current partitioning is).

The conclusion is you should adjust the parameter accordingly to the expected amount of data and desired parallelism. `coalesce(1)` as such is rarely useful in practice, especially in a context like streaming, where data properties can differ over time.

Comment: i have 2 datanodes, and my data is just 1mb file @user9985951