# NoSuchElementException Error in spark streaming query inspite of heavy cluster config

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, databricks

Can someone help me understand the cause behind this error:

```
ERROR Query alert [id = d19f51b1-8131-40dd-ab62, runId = 276833a0-235f-4d2e-bd61] terminated with error
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BasicWriteJobStatsTracker$.metrics(BasicWriteStatsTracker.scala:180)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink.basicWriteJobStatsTracker(FileStreamSink.scala:103)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink.addBatch(FileStreamSink.scala:140)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$5$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:568)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:240)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:97)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:170)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$5.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:566)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:251)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:565)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:207)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:175)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:175)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:251)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:175)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:169)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:296)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:208)
```

The cluster configs are:

Databricks runtime 5.5 LTS

Scala 2.11

Spark 2.4.3

Driver: 64GB mem, 16 cores, 3DBU

workers: 64GB mem, 16 cores, 3DBU (2-4 workers, auto scalable)

there are 3 streaming queries running in parallel as defined in fairscheduler.xml

Spark configs are:

```
spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=-1
spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=1200
spark.executor.instances=4
spark.executor.cores=16
spark.executor.memory=29g
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=32
spark.default.parallelism=32
spark.driver.maxResultSize=25g
spark.scheduler.mode=FAIR
spark.scheduler.allocation.file=/dbfs/config/fairscheduler.xml
```

Adding code flow below:

```
implicit class PipedObject[A](value: A) {
def conditionalPipe(f: A => A)(pred: Boolean): A =
  if (pred) f(value) else value
}
implicit val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("MyApp")
  .conditionalPipe(sess => sess.master("local[6]"))(false)
  .getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val cookedData = getCookedStreamingData() // streaming data as input from event hub
spark.sparkContext.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "cook")
cookedData.writeStream
          .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpointLocation1")
          .queryName("queryName1")
          .format("avro")
          .option("path", "dir1")
          .start()

val scoredData = score(cookedData)
spark.sparkContext.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "score")
scoredData.writeStream
          .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpointLocation2")
          .queryName("queryName2")
          .format("avro")
          .option("path", "dir2")
          .start()

val alertData = score(scoredData)
spark.sparkContext.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "alert")
alertData.writeStream
          .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpointLocation3")
          .queryName("queryName3")
          .format("avro")
          .option("path", "dir3")
          .start()
```

Sample fairScheduler.xml file:

```
<allocations>
<pool name="default">
    <schedulingMode>FIFO</schedulingMode>
    <weight>2</weight>
    <minShare>2</minShare>
</pool>
<pool name="cook">
    <schedulingMode>FAIR</schedulingMode>
    <weight>1</weight>
    <minShare>5</minShare>
</pool>
<pool name="score">
    <schedulingMode>FAIR</schedulingMode>
    <weight>1</weight>
    <minShare>5</minShare>
</pool>
<pool name="alert">
    <schedulingMode>FAIR</schedulingMode>
    <weight>1</weight>
    <minShare>5</minShare>
</pool>
</allocations>
```

Answer (score 0):

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get

is purely your scala programming bug. since there is no code snippet I could'nt able to point it.

If you are using options then before reading the element, you need to check

`isDefined` before using `get` on `Option`

or else you can use   `getOrElse()` function from the `Option` to supply a default value.

In case you are using multiple sparkcontext it may arise...

Have a look at this... [Spark Streaming Exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50987061/spark-streaming-exception-java-util-nosuchelementexception-none-get)

Comment: added more code for reference... I do not understand how multiple spark contexts are being created here...