# Why does java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get happened?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to classify some documents using Spark (3.3.2). First, I defined the `sparkSession` and obtained the `javaSparkContext`. Then, I read the corpus, collected them into `labeledWordList`, and put them into a `dataFrame`. After creating the pipeline model `pipelineModel`, I would like to test the model with training data which was splited using `randomSplit()`. The code is as following:

```java
package com.nova.spark.nlp;

import com.hankcs.hanlp.HanLP;
import com.nova.spark.logger.Log;
import com.nova.spark.model.CategorizedDocument;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline;
import org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel;
import org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage;
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression;
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator;
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.HashingTF;
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.IDF;
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.IndexToString;
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer;
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;
import scala.Tuple2;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PretrainModel {
    private static final String CORPUS_PATH = "src/main/resources/corpus min/";

    static {
        HanLP.Config.ShowTermNature = false;
        Log.getLogger().info("PretrainModel::static:Initialize");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Log.getLogger().info("PretrainModel::main:Start");
        File[] categories = new File(CORPUS_PATH).listFiles();
        assert categories != null;
        List<CategorizedDocument> labeledWordList = new ArrayList<>();

        SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
                .master("local[*]")
                .config("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
                .appName("PretrainModel::main")
                .getOrCreate();
        JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(sparkSession.sparkContext());
        for (File currentCorpusDirectory : categories) {
            String categoryName = currentCorpusDirectory.getName();
            if (categoryName.startsWith(".")) {
                continue;
            }
            Log.getLogger().info("PretrainModel::readCategorizedCorpus::Category-" + categoryName + ":Process");
            List<CategorizedDocument> categorizedDocuments = javaSparkContext
                    .wholeTextFiles(CORPUS_PATH + categoryName, 1)
                    .cache()
                    .map(Tuple2::_2)
                    .filter(line -> line.length() > 20)
                    .map(line -> String.join(" ", Processor.getSplitWords(line)))
                    .map(document -> new CategorizedDocument(categoryName, document))
                    .collect();
            labeledWordList.addAll(categorizedDocuments);
        }
        Log.getLogger().info("PretrainModel::main:Done");

        JavaRDD<Row> labeledWordRDD = javaSparkContext
                .parallelize(labeledWordList)
                .map(document -> RowFactory.create(document.getCategory(), document.getDocument()));
        StructField labelField = DataTypes.createStructField("category", DataTypes.StringType, false);
        StructField wordField = DataTypes.createStructField("document", DataTypes.StringType, false);
        StructType structType = DataTypes.createStructType(List.of(labelField, wordField));
        Dataset<Row> dataFrame = sparkSession.createDataFrame(labeledWordRDD, structType);
        Dataset<Row>[] randomSplits = dataFrame.randomSplit(new double[]{0.8, 0.2});
        Dataset<Row> trainDataFrame = randomSplits[0], testDataFrame = randomSplits[1];

        Tokenizer tokenizer = new Tokenizer()
                .setInputCol("document")
                .setOutputCol("words");
        HashingTF hashingTF = new HashingTF()
                .setInputCol("words")
                .setOutputCol("rawFeatures")
                .setNumFeatures(2000);
        IDF idf = new IDF()
                .setInputCol("rawFeatures")
                .setOutputCol("features")
                .setMinDocFreq(5);
        StringIndexer stringIndexer = new StringIndexer()
                .setInputCol("category")
                .setOutputCol("label");
        LogisticRegression logisticRegression = new LogisticRegression()
                .setMaxIter(10);
        IndexToString indexToString = new IndexToString()
                .setInputCol("prediction")
                .setOutputCol("class");
        Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline()
                .setStages(new PipelineStage[]{tokenizer, hashingTF, idf, stringIndexer, logisticRegression, indexToString});
        PipelineModel pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(trainDataFrame);
        Dataset<Row> predictedDataFrame = pipelineModel.transform(testDataFrame);
        predictedDataFrame.select("category", "label", "prediction", "class")
                .show(30, false);
        MulticlassClassificationEvaluator evaluator = new MulticlassClassificationEvaluator()
                .setLabelCol("label")
                .setPredictionCol("prediction")
                .setMetricName("accuracy");
        double accuracy = evaluator.evaluate(predictedDataFrame);
        System.out.println("Accuracy = " + accuracy);
    }
}
```

However, I encounter some exception like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:627)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:626)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.IndexToString.transform(StringIndexer.scala:605)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel.$anonfun$transform$4(Pipeline.scala:311)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.MLEvents.withTransformEvent(events.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.MLEvents.withTransformEvent$(events.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation.withTransformEvent(Instrumentation.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel.$anonfun$transform$3(Pipeline.scala:311)
    at scala.collection.ArrayOps$.foldLeft$extension(ArrayOps.scala:782)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel.$anonfun$transform$2(Pipeline.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.MLEvents.withTransformEvent(events.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.MLEvents.withTransformEvent$(events.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation.withTransformEvent(Instrumentation.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel.$anonfun$transform$1(Pipeline.scala:308)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.$anonfun$instrumented$1(Instrumentation.scala:191)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.instrumented(Instrumentation.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel.transform(Pipeline.scala:307)
    at com.nova.spark.nlp.PretrainModel.main(PretrainModel.java:101)
```

I have learnt the post [None.get when streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50987061/spark-streaming-exception-java-util-nosuchelementexception-none-get) carefully, and I maintain only one `javaSparkContext` (instead of mixing `javaSparkContext` and something like `sparkContext` together). Yet I still encounter the problem.

Comment: The stacktrace that is posted here differs quite a bit from the other stackoverflow answer. This looks like you're trying to access a field that does not exist.